# React Native ScrollView - How to scroll to a child component from another child component button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, scrollview

I have this structure with a ScrollView, which is a parent with 5 childs

Parent Component with ScrollView

- Component1
- Component2
- Component3
- Component4
- Component5

Inside Component3 I have a button that when pressed should scroll parent component ScrollView to Component5

Something like this

**Home (Parent)**

```html
export default class Home extends React.Component {      
    renderComments() {
        return this.state.dataSource.map(item =>
            <CommentDetail key={item.id} comment={item} />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>      
                <Component1 />
                <Component2 />
                <CentralElements  {...this.state.dataSource} scroll = {this.props.scroll} />
                <Component4 />                  
                <View>
                    {this.renderComments()}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

**CentralElements  (Component3)**

```html
export default class CentralElements extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
  
    goToComments= () => {
        this.props.scroll.scrollTo({x: ?, y: ?, animated: true});
     };

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToComments}>
                    <Image source={require('../../assets/image.png')} />
                    <Text>Comments</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                ...
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
};
```

And the Comments are the Component5, any idea on how to the parent scroll?
I trying to figure what I'm missing, since thats my first contact with this.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56065152/8031495
You can make some changes and can achieve the desired solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did was..
in component5 I call onLayout in the main view and then save `x` and `y` in the parent component.
To scroll to it in component 3 on click i call the parent function that uses the scrollview ref to scroll to the values stored before

Component5

```
    export default class Component5 extends Component {

    saveLayout() {
        this.view.measureInWindow((x, y, width, height) => {
            this.props.callParentFunction(x, y)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View ref={ref => this.view = ref} onLayout={() => this.saveLayout()}>

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Component3

```
export default class Component3 extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.props.goToComponent5()}}>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
this.goToComponent5=this.goToComponent5.bind(this)
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        x:0,
        y:0,
    }
}

    callParentFunction(x, y) {
        this.setState({ x, y })
    }

    goToComponent5(){
        this.ScrollView.scrollTo({x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y, animated: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View >
                <ScrollView ref={ref => this.ScrollView = ref}>
                    <Component1 />
                    <Component2 />
                    <Component3 goToComponent5={this.goToComponent5}/>
                    <Component4 />
                    <Component5 callParentFunction={this.callParentFunction}/>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks a very good way to go.  I guess one issue I'm missing is with width and height. I've got "this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({ x, y })', 'this.setState' is undefined )

Comment: I forgot to create the state, see edit. What's the issue about width and height?

Comment: Yeah, even with the state the issue persisted. I've tried with callParentFunction = (x, y) => {
        this.setState({ x, y });
    } Which worked

Comment: Now when I press I get "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.ScrollView.scrollTo')" Almost there I guess =)

Comment: See edit, that should work, the reason was probably `this` was not in scope of `goToComponent5`

Comment: I was just reading that! That I probably need to bind the context. Now it is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Vice-versa is possible.? I want to call Component5 method from Parent

Comment: @vickykeshri I'm not sure I understood but if you use refs your parent can have acess to all variables in component 5.

Comment: I tried with that, seems like we can use ref only for parent component. However renderMethod are not holding ref.

Comment: @vickykeshri What method are you trying to call?